# Foreign key composed of 2 columns with specific values

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Let's imagine I have 2 tables:

- `Regions` (RegionID, RegionName, RegionRank) where `RegionRank` can either be `Primary` or `Secondary`
- `Country` (CountryID, CountryName, Primary_RegionID, Secondary_RegionID)

A region table could look like:

```
RegionID  RegionName      RegionRank
1         Nordic          Primary
2         NordEuropean    Secondary
3         GermanSpeaking  Primary
4         Iberia          Primary
5         SouthEuropean   Secondary
```

A country table could look like:

```
CountryID  CountryName   Primary_RegionID    Secondary_RegionID
1          Sweden        1 (Nordic)          2 (NordEuropean)
2          Germany       3 (GermanSpeaking)  2 (NordEuropean)
3          Spain         4 (Iberia)          5 (SouthEuropean)
```

I would like to create 2 foreign key for `Country`.

1. `Country.Primary_RegionID =  fk_Primary_RegionID` that refers to `Region(RegionID, RegionRank = "Primary")`
2. `Country.Secondary_RegionID = fk_Primary_RegionID` that refers to    `Region(RegionID, RegionRank = "Secondary")`

How do I do that? How do I create a fk with such a check constraint? I could create 2 different tables (Region_Primary) and (Region_Secondary) but I don't find that an elegant solution. Perhaps it is easier.

Thanks

Comment: AFAIK it can't be done using only foreign key, but you can also add check constraints on your country table table will make sure it's impossible to set a secondary region to the Primary_RegionId

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit tricky, but you can do it using computed columns and additional unique keys.

```
alter table regions
    add constraint unique unq_regions_primary on (RegionRank, RegionName);

alter table countries add PrimaryRank as ('Primary');
alter table countries add SecondaryRank as ('Secondary');

alter table countries
    add constraint fk_countries_primary foreign key (PrimaryRank, Primary_RegionID) references regions (RegionRank, RegionId);

alter table countries
    add constraint fk_countries_secondary foreign key (SecondaryRank, Secondary_RegionID) references regions (RegionRank, RegionId);
```

Comment: I have followed your code. On the last step,  when i create the fk_countries_primary i get the following error message: "Msg 1776, Level 16, State 0, Line 10
There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table 'regions' that match the referencing column list in the foreign key 'fk_countries_primary'."   The PK of Regions is set to RegionID and unq_regions_primary does exists.

Comment: @Raul_Homburg . . . The candidate key should be created by the `unique` constraint.  Can you try creating a unique index instead?  (These should be equivalent.)

Comment: Thanks!!!! it works exactly as I wanted. Small changes: Instead of having columns PrimaryRank and SecondaryRank as calculated I changed them to "default values". In this way I circumvented problems with "No Persisted" calculated columns. Also I made a change on the unique key, your code  reads Unique(RegionRank, RegionName) but the FK refers to (PrimaryRank, Primary_RegionID). I changed the RegionName for RegionID and I all works perfectly well now. Thanks!